# How do I upgrade from Ubuntu 16.04.4 to 16.04.5?

Tags: 16.04, apt, upgrade, kernel, versions

I have done

```
sudo apt-get update  
sudo apt-get upgrade  
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Then I checked `lsb_release -a` which showed, still:

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS
Release:    16.04
Codename:   xenial
```

Some internet forum suggested (and this was for 16.04.2 -> 16.04.3) to make sure all deb packages in `/etc/apt/sources.list` are **not commented out** so I did that.

```
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security main restricted
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security main 
restricted
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security universe
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security universe
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security multiverse
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security multiverse
```

At this point I re-ran all initial steps and the dist-upgrade...
To no avail. And, there isn't any solution I can find.

As a side note: If you check the official ubuntu versions end of life support, 16.04.4's kernel (v.4.13) support ends this year, whereas 16.04.5 has a newer kernel (v.4.15), and has support through to 2021.

**So, how do I upgrade from Ubuntu 16.04.4 to 16.04.5 ?**

Comment: should I feel embarassed now? I probably should. Anyway, thanks.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. There is nothing to be embarrassed about. mistakes happen. Stick around.  Ask a new question if you have another problem. Answer one if you can help. As you get more reputation you will be able to help in other ways. See https://askubuntu.com/tour and https://askubuntu.com/help

Answer (score 4):

## You will need a time machine to go to the future.

To be precise Travel to approximately August 2, 2018. Then run the first three commands in your question. Once done you can use the same time machine to come back to the present.

See https://wiki.ubuntu.com/XenialXerus/ReleaseSchedule

## As a side note,

Canonical, the makers of Ubuntu will continue to patch the kernels used in the Ubuntu LTS 16.04 for five years from April, 2016. So, even if kernel v.4.13 reaches end of its life, for Ubuntu 16.04, it will continue to live a fruitful life till 2021.

You just have to make sure that you use the default kernels from the default Ubuntu repository and keep them updated as usual.

Hope this helps